# Where to send my research work for evaluation?

Tags: publications, independent-researcher, publishability

I have been doing some research (not connected to any university) on my own and written articles on different theories and models and hypotheses of management based on the application on maritime fiels. Some of the articles are only few pages and some are incomplete and I am still adding to them. These are my own work in the field but this is research-oriented and relates to the existing knowledge (not new knowledge) on the research topic that I have selected but it is totally my view. It may not contribute new knowledge beyond what’s currently available.

Now my question is: How do I know what is the value of my write-ups. Do my articles really mean anything? Who can tell? Where to send them to get an idea of these papers’ worth?

Comment: *These are my own work in the field but this is research-oriented and relates to the existing knowledge (not new knowledge) on the research topic that I have selected but it is totally my view.* – I fail to understand this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are looking for is a [peer review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review). This is the first step after you submitted your work to a scientific journal that covers your field of work. Its purpose is to ensure the quality of your work and the contribution it makes to ongoing research. This said, in order to publish something in a scientific journal, you should have brought "something new" to the table. Nonetheless submitting your article will certainly lead to some feedback.

The second option I see and that you should consider first is finding a person on a close by university, who might help you out by reading part of your article and giving you some feedback.

Comment: Note that having people available to review your work is one of the reasons for enrolling at or working at a university...